# I noticed some suspicious voting patterns, what should I do?

Tags: discussion, voting

Pretty much everything is in the title: what should I do when if I noticed suspicious voting patterns? Should I do anything at all?

I mean [there are mechanisms](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) which should deal with that but I'm not sure whether they're scaled down to the size of typical immature SE site, which PMSE currently is.

**UPDATE:** As another flavor of this question: what if the problem doesn't touch PMSE only but can also be seen on other SE sites?

Answer (score 2):

If it is an individual site, mod flag one relevant post with a description.

If it is on multiple network sites, email the address provided at the bottom of every page.

We always follow up on reports of gaming or exploits!

Answer (score 1):

The #1 tool you have at your disposal for reporting issues to moderators is the flagging system.  You can flag questions and answers for moderator attention.

In addition, if flagging will not be sufficient, suspicious behavior can be reported to the moderators by sending an email to team+pm@stackexchange.com.

Comment: How do I flag a specific vote? I mean it's not a single vote which is wrong - any single one of them is OK. It's the whole pattern which concerns me.

Comment: @pawel - In that case, you could send us an email with links to the questions/answers you consider suspicious.  We also have tools that show us suspicious voting patterns between different users.